# Turn a particular grammar into LL 1 grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

Suppose we have the following CFG:

```
A → Bd
B → dA|a|ɛ
```

Now if I try to calculate **FIRST** and **FOLLOW** sets, I think I can get it done as follows:

```
First(A) = { d, a }
First(B) = { d, a, ɛ }

FOLLOW(A) = { d, $ }
FOLLOW(B) = { d }
```

And the parser table must be this:

```
+---+--------+------------------+---+
|   |    a   |         d        | $ |
+===+========+==================+===+
| A | A → Bd |      A → Bd      |   |
+---+--------+------------------+---+
| B |  B → a | B → dA and B → ɛ |   |
+---+--------+------------------+---+
```

Now we have multiple entries for our table.
What is the correct way to build an LL(1) parsing table for this grammar?

Comment: You say `FOLLOW(A) = { d, a }`. That means there is some sentential form containing `...Ad...`, and another one containing `...Aa...`. What are these sentential forms, and how are they derived? (Asking for a friend, as they say.)

Comment: Yes, you're right sir. I changed it.

Comment: 1:A→Bd  (replace B with dA) 2:A→dAd

Comment: Ok, so you have a real LL(1) conflict. Are you supposed to fix the grammar? Because the parsing table reflects the grammar. (It should have at least one `$` entry, though: you're still missing the `$` in FOLLOW(A), assuming `A` is the start symbol.)

Comment: I supposed to either fix it or give a proof to show that it can't be converted to LL(1) grammar.